# Proof of Transitivity (Inference Rule) using Leibniz rule and Equanimity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In Tourlakis' Mathematical logic, we are given the following primitive rules of inference [p.40]:

- Leibniz rule: (A↔B) / (C[p≔A]↔C[p≔B])
- Equanimity: (A, A↔B) / B

[Capture from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgH6v.png)

Then he goes to derive the following inference rule, using he previous two [p.47]:

- Transitivity: (A↔B, B↔C) / (A↔C)

[Capture from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msYqy.png)

I have trouble proving how to use the primitive rules to proof Transitivity.

Leibniz rule: I understand that the Leibniz rule replaces in C (which is well formed formulae) any occurrence of the Boolean variable (atomic) **p** with A to get C[p≔A] and then replaces **p** with B to get C[p≔B], which yields to C[p≔A]↔C[p≔B].

Equanimity: If we assume A to be **t** and A↔B to be **t**, (because that's our premise), we get that B must be also **t**, because that's required for A↔B to be **t**.

Now, I don't see how to use either of the primitive formulae to prove Transitivity, I don't quite get how to use the Leibniz rule in Tourlakis' way. I would even go further and to state Transitivity as another primitive rule of inference, but I think just two is a nicer approach.

So, how to prove Transitivity using Leibniz and Equanimity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note*: due to the fact that the example uses $A,B,C$ as schematic letters for formulas, I'll adopt a different letter for the formulation of Leibniz's rule:

> from $A \equiv B$, infer $X[p := A] \equiv X[p := B]$.

Thus, to apply the rule with premise $B \equiv C$, we use as $X$ the formula $A \equiv p$.

The two substitutions are: $X[p := B] = (A \equiv p)[p := B] = A \equiv B$ and  $X[p := C] = (A \equiv p)[p := C] = A \equiv C$, respectively.

In conclusion:

1. $A \equiv B$
2. $B \equiv C$
3. $X[p := B] \equiv X[p := C] \text {  i.e.  } A \equiv B \equiv A \equiv C$ --- from 1) and 2) by Leibniz.

Regarding

> in step "we use as $X$ the formula $A≡p$" we assume the formula $A$ to be atomic, so that, when replacing $p$ in $X$ for $A$ we get $A$,

the answer is: no. We assume as $X$ the "composite" formula $A \equiv p$, where $p$ is atomic.

Comment: Then, in this step "we use as C the formula A≡p." we assume the formulae A to be atomic, so that, when replacing p in C for A we get A. However, the Leibniz rule does not assume C to be atomic, neither in specific to be equal to p, which I think would count as a instance of the Leibniz Rule, but not as the general rule. So, we derive Transivity only if we assume C to be p, which is what Tourlakis didn't stated in his book. Thank you so much, Mauro!